# Should reverse-dns and ptr-record be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tags [reverse-dns](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/reverse-dns) and [ptr-record](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ptr-record) are obviously highly related. Are they so related to each other, that it would be better to have them merged as a single tag?

If it is desirable to keep them as separate tags, then what are examples of questions that could reasonably be tagged with one of the two tags, but not the other?

I want to point out that we do have tags for other DNS record types as well, for example [cname-record](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cname-record) and [mx-record](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/mx-record). I assume we want to keep this consistent across record types. Does that get en the way of a merge?

Comment: Last time I did a rough count we had already 5000+ tags (and too many with hardly associated questions) so anything that reduces that number is fine by me. ☺

Answer (score 10):

I can't imagine any questions which would be tagged as one or the other.  That says to me that it would be reasonable to make one a synonym of the other.  I'm not sure about which one to make the "primary", though.

I can see the value in consistency of tag name with other DNS record types, so [ptr-record](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ptr-record) would seem to be the better primary.  On the other hand, the term "reverse DNS" is almost certainly the more commonly known term.  Google says `"PTR record"` gets 353k results, while `"reverse DNS"` gets 608k results.  Hmm, that's not as wide a gulf as I had expected...

At any rate, I'm all in favour of merging and synonymising the tags.

Comment: I'd go with 'reverse DNS' as the primary.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I just tried suggesting that synonym. I got an error message saying "Failed to propose synonym:

Reverse synonym ptr-record already proposed on the tag ptr"

Comment: Maybe we need to make `ptr` a synonym of `reverse-dns` then?

Comment: @womble Trying to suggest that produce a different error message: "Failed to propose synonym:

The suggested tag must exist in the system before suggesting it as a synonym!"

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I agree totally

PTR record would be more accurate to be equal categories for the tags: A, MX, NS, PTR, TXT...

Reverse-DNS, rDNS and FCrDNS should be related to the pairing of an A record and PTR record.

Those with issues with reverse DNS are related to identity verification (ssh keys, email, syslog, netflow)